# axios set headers in config vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios

Right now I use axios like this:

```
import axios from 'axios'
axios.get(apiObjUrl,
  {
     headers: {
               'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
              }
  })
   .then(({data}) => {
```

How do I set global axios header?
(I need to set localization header to use in all my requests)

Answer (score 0):

Use an Axios interceptor: https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#interceptors

In `config` you have the request's headers.

Comment: can you provide an example of using interceptor?

Comment: axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    // Do something before request is sent
    return config;
  }, function (error) {
    // Do something with request error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });

Comment: please consider at least adding a part of the link config to your answer since link only answers can become invalid if the link changes.